# How to set the width of multiple element with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a bootstrap app in my project.

In my example, I want 3 yellow columns width to match the 3 green columns width. How do I do it?

```
html:
<div id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="title-wrapper" class="col-xs-8">            
            <div id="wrapper1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                        title-col-1
                    </div>
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                        title-col-2
                    </div>
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                        title-col-3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="wrapper" class="col-xs-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="col1" class="col-xs-3">
                            <p>Col 1</p>
                            <p>Col 1</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col2" class="col-xs-3">
                            <p>Col 2</p>
                            <p>Col 2</p>
                       </div>
                       <div id="col3" class="col-xs-3">
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                       </div>
                    </div>    
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="second" class="col-xs-4">
            <p>second </p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS
#main{
    background-color:red;
    height:300px;
}

#second{
    background-color:blue;
}

.first-table{
    background-color:green;
    border:solid 1px black;
}

#wrapper{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}

#col1, #col2, #col3{
    background:yellow;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
```

JS Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/a1zpb8su/2/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a CSS class that you can set specific elements with one common width. This will give you total control over which elements will have the same width.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="title-wrapper" class="col-xs-8">            
            <div id="wrapper1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3 match-width">
                        title-col-1
                    </div>
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3 match-width">
                        title-col-2
                    </div>
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3 match-width">
                        title-col-3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="wrapper" class="col-xs-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="col1" class="col-xs-3 match-width">
                            <p>Col 1</p>
                            <p>Col 1</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col2" class="col-xs-3 match-width">
                            <p>Col 2</p>
                            <p>Col 2</p>
                       </div>
                       <div id="col3" class="col-xs-3 match-width">
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                            <p>Col 3</p>
                       </div>
                    </div>    
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="second" class="col-xs-4">
            <p>second </p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS:**

```
.match-width {
    width: 100px;   
}
```

[***Working Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/juy1tbwt/)

Comment: Thanks but it won't be responsive once you set the width to 100px.

Comment: This is no for responsive. Topic author dont use a right bootstrap shematic to make this working. :)

Answer (score 0):

You had your second row inside your first; they were nested. you also had one col set to `col-xs-8` and the other set to `col-xs-9`. I made them both `col-xs-8` to work with `col-xs-4`

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="title-wrapper" class="col-xs-8">            
            <div id="wrapper1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                        title-col-1
                    </div>
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                        title-col-2
                    </div>
                    <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                        title-col-3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div id="second" class="col-xs-4">
            <p>second </p> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- moved this row out of the other -->
    <div class="row">
        <div id="wrapper" class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="col1" class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Col 1</p>
                    <p>Col 1</p>
                </div>
                <div id="col2" class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Col 2</p>
                    <p>Col 2</p>
               </div>
               <div id="col3" class="col-xs-3">
                    <p>Col 3</p>
                    <p>Col 3</p>
                    <p>Col 3</p>
                    <p>Col 3</p>
                    <p>Col 3</p>
               </div>
            </div>    
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: If you want to keep them nested, use this

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="first-table col-xs-3">title-col-1</div>
            <div class="first-table col-xs-3">title-col-2</div>
            <div class="first-table col-xs-3">title-col-3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="col1" class="col-xs-3">
                <p>Col 1</p>
                <p>Col 1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="col2" class="col-xs-3">
                <p>Col 2</p>
                <p>Col 2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="col3" class="col-xs-3">
                <p>Col 3</p>
                <p>Col 3</p>
                <p>Col 3</p>
                <p>Col 3</p>
                <p>Col 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p>second </p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There really is not much of a need to have nested rows. We can just remove those, the unused classes and id's. Then place `second` in the first row, and make it a `div` other than `p` so it takes the same space has your header. Also for the same width you want to set both to `col-xs-8`, other than `col-xs-8` and `col-xs-9`

Here are the changes: [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a1zpb8su/29/)

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="title-wrapper" class="col-xs-8">            
            <div>
                <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                    title-col-1
                </div>
                <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                    title-col-2
                </div>
                <div class="first-table col-xs-3">
                    title-col-3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="second" class="col-xs-4">
            <div>second </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div id="col1" class="col-xs-3">
                <p>Col 1</p>
                <p>Col 1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="col2" class="col-xs-3">
                <p>Col 2</p>
                <p>Col 2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="col3" class="col-xs-3">
                <p>Col 3</p>
                <p>Col 3</p>
                <p>Col 3</p>
                <p>Col 3</p>
                <p>Col 3</p>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

You need make columns on right place, and also rows need placed correctly. Bootstrap on wrapping use a class name `container.

Also you need use structure:

`<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">`

If on parent col is children cols, you need wrap it intro row class.

http://jsfiddle.net/a1zpb8su/24/